# Source maps not working VSCode debugger Typescript

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework, vscode-debugger, source-maps, esbuild

I realise this is a heavily asked question but through all the articles I have read, I have not yet found a solution.

I'm trying to debug my serverless Typescript project using VSCode debugger. Setting breakpoints in the code is fine & they are hit but when trying to output the values of variables in the debug console, I always get a `ReferenceError: x is not defined`. This, to me, sounds like it cannot find the source maps created. I am using [serverless-esbuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-esbuild) to transpile the TS.

The custom config for that package in `serverless.yml` is minimal being:

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  esbuild:
    bundle: true
    minify: true
    sourcemap: true
```

The `sourcemap` option in esbuild creating the source maps & linking them to the transpiled JS files by setting:

`//# sourceMappingURL=`

at the end of the `.js` files.

My project structure is:

```
.esbuild/
├─ .build/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ index.js
│  │  ├─ index.js.map
src/
├─ index.ts
tsconfig.json
serverless.yml
package.json
```

The `.esbuild` folder being created by esbuild. My `index.ts` is really basic with:

```js
export const handler = (event) => {
    const msg: string = 'Hello World'

    console.log(msg)
}
```

My `launch.json` is:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Serverless",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "debug"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_modules>/**"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "type": "node",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/.esbuild/.build/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `debug` script in package.json is:

`export SLS_DEBUG=* && node --inspect --enable-source-maps /usr/local/bin/serverless offline --stage dev`

When I run the configuration it works as expected with saying it exposes the functions in question *(i.e. "Greeting" function)*. I then invoke the lambda from the terminal using the AWS CLI with:

`aws lambda invoke /dev/null --endpoint-url http://localhost:3002 --function-name Greeting`

If I put a breakpoint on the `console.log(msg)` line then the breakpoint will be hit which is great but if I try to log out the value of `msg` in the console it throws back:

"ReferenceError: msg is not defined"

but if I play over that line, it will output the `msg` correctly in the console so this seems like an issue to do with the debugger not finding the source maps but the `outFiles` property in the config seems correct so I cannot see what is wrong here.

**EDIT:**

If I make the additional config in launch.json:

```json
{
    "name": "Invoke function",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/serverless",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_modules>/**"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "invoke",
        "local",
        "-f",
        "Greeting"
    ],
    "type": "node"
}
```

So using `serverless invoke local` I get the same result, breakpoint is hit but can't output the values

Comment: make sure you start Node.js with `--enable-source-maps` flag, otherwise it won't pickup source maps